# UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard in Action Extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I've been working on an Action Extension since beta 1. It is a URL shortner via bitly.com. When the URL is shortened it is copied to the user's pasteboard

`UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().URL = shortUrl`

This was working fine the last time I checked in beta 5. As of GM it seems we no longer have access to the pasteboard?

`po UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().URL`

Returns nil in scenarios that I know there is something there, and when I verify that shortUrl indeed contains a value, the assignment is ignored. Printing `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().URL` always returns nil while debugging the extension.

Was access to the pasteboard removed? It seems to be a silent failure if so.

I have also reproduced this in Objective-C, so it is not a Swift issue.

**Update**

I tried this in an extension that has user interface (there are two types of action extensions, those without and those with). For those *with* UI, the pasteboard works as expected. So this seems isolated to action extensions without UI.

I also reported a bug on this.

**Update 2**

I believe this to be a bug, Apple closed my radar as a duplicate.

Comment: I tried this in iOS 11 and it worked fine in both kinds of action extension. So if this was a bug, it is now fixed; action extensions are allowed to set the pasteboard.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running into the same issue as well.  I'm using it in objective-C though.  Tried the pasteboard in it's simplest form and still nothing.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setString:@"copied string"];
```

The above code works fine in the containing app though.

**Update:**
For those still searching for an answer and wanting to use the pasteboard with the *custom keyboard extension*, I came across this post: [iOS8 Custom Keyboard - Copy & Paste to UIPasteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25978977/4048853)

You will need to allow BOTH full access in your plist file and allow full access in the keyboard settings in the Settings.app.

Comment: @Chris I'm using the keyboard extension but have the same issue.  Something I noticed to is that it's working fine in the simulator, just not on a device.  It very well might be a bug.  I'll file a bug report as too.

Also I’m too new to stackoverflow to comment on anyone’s post except my own, :p