# iOS8 Custom Keyboard - Copy & Paste to UIPasteboard

Tags: swift, uikit, ios8

Is it possible to copy text/image to UIPasteboard in a keyboard extension? Similar to what [popkey.co](http://popkey.co) does with animated images.

I tested the following code and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
func copyImage() {
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "copy test"
}
```

It always shows this error message:

> UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support

Do you know about any other way to use copy&paste from a keyboard extension?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to do it if I gave my custom keyboard "Full Access" in the Settings->General->Keyboard app.
You need to include "RequestsOpenAccess" = YES in your Info.plist file.  AND you have to toggle "Full Access" on in the Settings app.

Seems like Apple is restricting access to the general UIPasteboard otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've tried to add it to the Info.plist file but still no luck. I don't get the error anymore (even with the original file for some reason) but `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()` returns nil.

Comment: You're right, it was an issue of the "full access". I added it to root of the Info.plist but it must be done in **Info.plist -> NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> RequestsOpenAccess -> YES** Thanks for your help!

Comment: It has to be set in the info.plist of your keyboard extension, not from your containing app

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to get full access to your custom keyboard for use images / gifs ...
on the iPhone Settings -> General -> Keyboards -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard... (Select your keyboard under THIRD-PARTY KEYBOARDS) -> click on your keyboard and toggle Allow Full Access

To do that you have to go to the to set RequestsOpenAccess = YES in the info.plist located in the keyboard extension folder.

Info.plist -> NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> RequestsOpenAccess -> YES

The following method will get the button tag check the tag in the switch statement and set the correct image according to the button tag to the pasteboard.

```
func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var btn = sender as UIButton

    switch (btn.tag){
    case 5:
       let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cat", ofType: "png")
       let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageURL!)!);
       UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "public.png")

    case 10:
       let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dog", ofType: "png")
       let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageURL!)!);
       UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "public.png")
   }}
```

User then can paste the image to any supported application...

Hope this helps !

Comment: Is it possible to paste the image automatically?

Comment: @Veilkrand no it is not possible to paste image automatically. You need to copy the image to UiPasteboard and paste it into the input view.