# iOS8 Custom Keyboard UIPasteBoard issue

Tags: ios, ios8, uipasteboard, custom-keyboard

I'm having issues with `UIPasteBoard` in my custom keyboard for iOS8.
When trying to initialise `UIPasteBoard` I get the following error:

> UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed
>   in UIKit.framework/Support

I already added `RequestsOpenAccess` to my info.plist of the keyboard target according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957366/ios8-custom-keyboard-copy-paste-to-uipasteboard) SA post.

I tried adding `UIKit.framework` to the keyboard target and importing it in my `KeyboardViewController` but without succes.

Anyone got an idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some headache and searching this was my solution.
Seems like an(other) iOS8 bug

- Remove the container app + the keyboard
- Reinstall the app + keyboard
- Switch full access off + on at keyboard settings

Answer (score 0):

Above is also right. but you have to add this also

Info.plist -> NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> RequestsOpenAccess -> YES

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer but it was not the problem in my case. As stated in the question, I already added the key to my plist