# Custom Keyboard Full Access Rejection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I had made a custom sticker keyboard. Basically users touches one of the gif images that I have placed on the keyboard, i do a a copy action on that image and then the user pastes it to iMessages. For this to work i need to have user do "Allow Full Access". Without it the copy action doesn't work. Now, my app got rejected with this message

> From Apple
> 25.5 - Keyboard extensions must remain functional with no network access or they will be rejected
>
> 25.5 Details We noticed that your keyboard extension does not function when the “Full Access” setting is toggled off.

Is there anything i need to set in my info.plist file? Did the reviewer didn't understand how my app works i.e. need to do rejection appeal or do I need to do something else? Trust me i googled but didn't find much on this topic

Comment: Your keyboard must provide some level of functionality without "Allow full access".  You may provide additional functionality if full access is granted but you cannot require it.  I haven't tried myself, but nothing in the app extension programming guide mentions UIPasteBoard limitations without full access.  Are the gifs contained in your app or on the network?

Comment: gifs are within my app and there is some sort of limitation with UIPasteBoard and keyboard extension. Just for fun of it i downloaded free grumpoji app (grumpy cat keyboard) on my iphone. It too also has sticker only keyboard and if you turn off "Allow full access" then the copy action of stickers doesn't work either. so its just not me. I think the reviewer had no idea and he just rejected the app.

Comment: Does your keyboard have *any* functionality without allow full access?

Comment: @Paulw11 - need to give full access for UIPasteBoard - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957366/ios8-custom-keyboard-copy-paste-to-uipasteboard

Comment: @Sam B - did you solved this issue ?

Comment: did you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question that eventually led to my app approval.

It doesn't matter if your app is custom sticker keyboard only. It "must" have "both" alphabet and numeric keyboards. If it doesn't then it will be rejected.

From Apple [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)
4.4.1 Keyboard extensions have some additional rules.
They must:

- Provide keyboard input functionality (e.g. typed characters);
- Provide
  a method for progressing to the next keyboard;
- Remain functional
  without full network access;
- Provide Number and Decimal keyboard
  types as described in the App Extension Programming Guide;

Comment: Whats the mean of "Remain functional without full network access" can you explain more.