Pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not available at this time
I am developing a keyboard extension app and it has a clipboard feature. The app is being developed in SwiftUI and displayed in the KeyboardViewController using a HostingController. So when the keyboard is launched, the KeyboardViewController displays a SwiftUI view and the SwiftUI view runs a function on onAppear to access the pasteboard. Here's the code:
func processClipboardContent() {
    print("Running")
    if let copiedItem = UIPasteboard.general.string, !copiedItem.isEmpty {
        print(copiedItem)
    } else {
        print("No text available in pasteboard or pasteboard access error.")
    }
}

But I get these in the print log:
Running
2024-07-31 13:33:47.651443+0530 FlexiBoard[41320:1487576] [Pasteboard] ...retrieving pasteboard named com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=10 "Pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not available at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not available at this time.}
2024-07-31 13:33:47.653580+0530 FlexiBoard[41320:1487576] [Pasteboard] ...retrieving pasteboard named com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=10 "Pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not available at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not available at this time.}
2024-07-31 13:33:47.655729+0530 FlexiBoard[41320:1487576] [Pasteboard] ...saving pasteboard failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=11 "The pasteboard name com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not valid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The pasteboard name com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not valid.}
2024-07-31 13:33:47.655828+0530 FlexiBoard[41320:1487576] Could not save pasteboard named com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general. Error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=11 "The pasteboard name com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not valid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The pasteboard name com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not valid.}
No text available in pasteboard or pasteboard access error.

I did some research and I learned that you cannot access the pasteboard when the app is in the background, but here it's not in the background, it's in the foreground. This issue only happens on real devices and not on simulators.

Did you set RequestsOpenAccess to YES in Info.plist? The user also needs to grant your keyboard full access in the Settings app. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25957366/5133585

Yes, I have set that and on the device I have allowed full access. Btw I forgot to mention, this problem only happens on real devices, not on the simulator.

@AbdullahAjmal I'm facing same error log as yours, did your figured it out?

@ChengEn yes, the problem was calling the hostingController from viewDidLoad while having the onAppear on the SwiftUI view. This is what gives that warning. What I did was, I moved the processClipboardContent to viewDidAppear and that seemed to fix the issue. If you need further help, let me know.

You're very kind @AbdullahAjmal, I did a little tweak and it did worked, thanks!
